# How to create an automation test for a workflow

Tags: c#, testing, integration-testing, mstest

I am working on a workflow project that has 19 scenarios for testing the whole system and 34 steps.

So, my question is, how can I create an automation test for it?

My current approach is:
Create an integrated test per each scenario, and then create the main system test to run all integrated tests.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace Project1
{
     // Unit tests
    public class UnitTest_step1
    {
        public void RunTest() { }
    }

    public class UnitTest_step2
    {
        public void RunTest() { }
    }

    public class UnitTest_step3
    {
        public void RunTest() { }
    }

    public class UnitTest_step4
    {
        public void RunTest() { }
    }
     // End of unit tests

    public class IntegrationTests
    {

        public void IntegrationTest1()
        {
            UnitTest_step1.RunTest();
            UnitTest_step2.RunTest();
            UnitTest_step4.RunTest();
        }

        public void IntegrationTest2()
        {
            UnitTest_step1.RunTest();
            UnitTest_step2.RunTest();
            UnitTest_step3.RunTest();
            UnitTest_step4.RunTest();
        }

        public void IntegrationTest3()
        {
            UnitTest_step1.RunTest();
            UnitTest_step4.RunTest();
        }

    }



    [TestClass]
    public class SystemTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Scenario1()
        {
            IntegrationTests.IntegrationTest1()
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Scenario2()
        {
            IntegrationTests.IntegrationTest2();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Scenario3()
        {
            IntegrationTests.IntegrationTest3();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ScenarioN()
        {
            IntegrationTests.IntegrationTestN();
        }
    }
}
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in my opinion, the information provided in your question is very abstract and the question is a bit too broad.
The answer depends on how your workflow engine is implemented and what are your system requirements.
Requirements and implementation details are what defines your approach to testing.

I would start with clarifying what kind of steps you have, is there any data context is passed,
what side effects these steps produce (writes data to database, sends events, call other system APIs, etc.),
do steps depend on each other and so on.

Another question is how do you need to assert the results, after each step or after scenario?
The system should be testable and normally, each step should be covered with unit tests.
So, suggested hypothetical approach is to cover each step with isolated unit tests 
and scenarios with integration tests.

I came up with a simple example just to illustrate one of the general approaches.
For simplicity, I assume that steps have little or no data context and can be reordered.

```
namespace Workflow.Test
{
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    [TestClass]
    public class SystemTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Scenario1()
        {
            new Workflow().Run(new Scenario1());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Scenario2()
        {
            new Workflow().Run(new Scenario2());
        }

        // The advantage of explicit steps declaration is test readability.
        // Declarative approach also enables the further possibility of test generation!
        [TestMethod]
        public void MoreExplicitAndDeclarative()
        {
            new Workflow().Run(new List<Type>
            {
                typeof(Step1),
                typeof(Step2),
                typeof(Step3),
            });
        }

        // Step instantiation may be needed if you want to parameterize some steps.
        [TestMethod]
        [DataRow("Custom step")]
        [DataRow("Another step")]
        public void MoreExplicitParameterizedScenario(string customName)
        {
            new Workflow().Run(new List<IRunnable>{
                new Step1(),
                new Step3(customName)
            });
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class StepsUnitTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Step1DoesWhatWeWant()
        {
            // Mock dependencies

            new Step1().Run();

            // Assert results
        }
    }

    #region Workflow Engine Example

    public interface IRunnable
    {
        void Run();
    }

    public class Workflow
    {
        public void Run(Scenario scenario)
        {
            Run(CreateSteps(scenario.GetStepTypes()));
        }

        public void Run(IEnumerable<Type> stepTypes)
        {
            Run(CreateSteps(stepTypes));
        }

        public void Run(List<IRunnable> steps)
        {
            steps.ForEach(step => step.Run());
        }

        private List<IRunnable> CreateSteps(IEnumerable<Type> stepTypes)
        {
            var steps = new List<IRunnable>();
            foreach (var stepType in stepTypes)
            {
                steps.Add(CreateStep(stepType));
            }

            return steps;
        }

        private IRunnable CreateStep(Type stepType)
            => (IRunnable) Activator.CreateInstance(stepType);
    }

    #endregion


    // Step structure can differ according to system requirements.
    // We may add data context and link steps into pipeline if needed.
    #region Steps

    public abstract class Step : IRunnable
    {
        private readonly string _stepName;

        protected Step(string name)
        {
            _stepName = name;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{_stepName} in action.");
            Invoke();
        }

        public abstract void Invoke();
    }

    public class Step1 : Step
    {
        public Step1() : base(nameof(Step1))
        {
        }

        public override void Invoke()
        {
            // do work
            Console.WriteLine($"Step1 invoked.");
        }
    }

    public class Step2 : Step
    {
        public Step2() : base(nameof(Step2))
        {
        }

        public override void Invoke()
        {
            // do work
            Console.WriteLine($"Step2 invoked.");
        }
    }

    public class Step3 : Step
    {
        public Step3(string customName) : base(customName)
        {

        }

        public Step3() : this(nameof(Step3))
        {
        }

        public override void Invoke()
        {
            // do work
            Console.WriteLine($"Step3 invoked.");
        }
    }

    public class Step4 : Step
    {
        public Step4() : base(nameof(Step4))
        {
        }

        public override void Invoke()
        {
            // do work
            Console.WriteLine($"Step4 invoked.");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    // Scenarios should be as declarative as possible.
    // Let's say the scenario is just specification of what steps (step Type)
    // and in what order should be executed (List as a non-unique ordered collection).
    #region Scenarios

    public abstract class Scenario
    {
        public abstract List<Type> GetStepTypes();
    }

    public class Scenario1 : Scenario
    {
        public override List<Type> GetStepTypes()
            => new List<Type>
            {
                typeof(Step1),
                typeof(Step2),
                typeof(Step3)
            };
    }

    public class Scenario2 : Scenario
    {
        public override List<Type> GetStepTypes()
            => new List<Type>
            {
                typeof(Step1),
                typeof(Step2),
                typeof(Step4)
            };
    }

    #endregion
}
```